# Why the Label text disappear when adding its View in a toolbar?

Tags: swift, button, swiftui, label, toolbar

I created a View that displays a button which has a Label with name and icon.

```
struct NewWordButtonView: View {

    @State var isAlert: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        Button {
            isAlert.toggle()
        } label: {
            Label("change word", systemImage: "arrow.triangle.2.circlepath").fixedSize()
        }
    .buttonStyle(.bordered)
    }
}
```

And it should look like this:

[image]

But when I add the View in a toolbar as a toolbar item the text disappear and only the icon remains.
Like this:

[image]

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set [`titleAndIcon`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/labelstyle/titleandicon) label style to your `label`, this will make sure to show both title and icon of the label.

```
Label("change word", systemImage: "arrow.triangle.2.circlepath")
    .labelStyle(.titleAndIcon)
    .fixedSize()
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case .labelStyle(.titleAndAction) didn't help to display text next to the icon.

To display icon **and text** of a button **inside toolbar**, replace Label(...) with Text(...) and Image(..) and put it into HStack:

```
HStack {
    Image(systemName: "arrow.triangle.2.circlepath")
    Text("change word")
}
```